# What's the proper way to use different pipenv environments for a Django project on different computer systems?

Tags: django, pipenv

Hopefully this isn't too stupid of a question, concerning the use of pipenv for the same Django project on different computer systems.  The scenario is that I'm using pipenv with a test Django project on one laptop, everything works fine, using VS Code and it's using the proper pipenv environment for the Python environment within VS Code.

The project however is within Dropbox so when I'm using a different laptop, which I do sometimes, one is my work laptop the other is my personal one at home, I can work on the same project wherever I left off.  So you can probably deduce the issue I'm having.

I'm using pipenv environment A on my work laptop for the Django project.  But when I open the project in VS Code on my personal laptop at home I have to keep specifying the proper pipenv environment to use, which obviously is different than the one on my work laptop.

Maybe I shouldn't be working this way and should just work on one laptop for the project, but I imagine others have done the same with similar setups before.

Is there a "proper" way to do this, using different pipenv environments on different machines for the same Django project?  Should I copy over the pipenv environment to each machine as well?  Or am I missing something really simple here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use version control.  (*git is the defacto standard these days and there are plenty of services to choose from*)

For using pipenv, you want to keep your Pipfile and Pipfile.lock in your repository (these are the only files you should be *copying* related to your environment from system to system).

The local environment is then built on *each* machine where it is needed by using `pipenv sync` or `pipenv sync --dev` (to install dev specific requirements).

So the related *virtualenv* will be created on each system in which you are developing your project.

Comment: Oh wow, that's fantastic, thanks for the information!  I figured it was something simple that was confusing me.  I'm still new to using virtual environments with Python, that makes total sense.

Comment: No problem, the pipenv docs explain this some where, but the docs site appears to be down atm.